# Allowing user to customise data on an SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to figure out how (if it is even possible) to allow a user to add a 'flag' to say when they have actioned a row in an SSRS report. This would need to carry back into the underlying tables.

Any help is appreciated; whether it is telling me this is impossible or giving me an idea of where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible in Reporting Services. You will need to look into building your own solution in .NET

Comment: Thank you! Was getting this impression unfortunately

Comment: @Teddysted its actually fairly easy to build in .net, I started to build a similar thing a few months back with my only experience being front end web design and now I am addicted!

Comment: @NeilNorris I will have a look into that then!

Comment: I highly recommend any of the Wrox .net books, all are excellent

Comment: @Teddysted, you may also find that working through this tutorial is a good starting point https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj943772.aspx

Comment: @PaulBambury Thank you; will begin having a look now!

Comment: @NeilNorris Will have a look at those if I get stuck. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @PaulBambury is right, the msdn tutorials will give you a nice base to work from, dont forget the c# chat room as well on here